# NoSuchElementException xPath mistake in python

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, xpath

I cannt figure out where is my mistake...

The html code is:

```
<div class="P(16px) C($c-secondary) BreakWord Whs(pl)">
    <div class="">
        <span class="">some text1 to retrieve</span>
        <span class="">some text2 to retrieve</span> 
   </div>
</div>
```

I have NoSuchElementException... with this xPath :

```
descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'BreakWord')/div/span")
```

help please ?

Comment: Can you share the rest of the html or a link to it please?

Comment: All code is extracted from Tinder, this is the "description" field of a profile when opened (up arrow). This block of html have been cleanly extracted from the all html page exactly as is... It must works and I dont see why not... I have tried with * instead of div also...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have just miss the closing `]` bracket.

Try now

```
descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'BreakWord')]/div/span")
```

Or

```
descriptions = browser.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'BreakWord')]//span")
```

Or following `css selector`.

```
descriptions =browser.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.BreakWord>div>span")
```

Comment: Thx u very much. I'm dying, I've been reading the line tens of time... Why does Spyder do not detect such error, any solution for raising an explicite error ? Thx

Comment: You can try on `chrome dev` tool  to check whether your `xpath` finds the matching count.